# Reading build/outputs/logs File from Gradle/Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-manifest, butterknife

I noticed my Android app was requesting to "Prevent phone from sleeping" when users installed it. I know I didn't add in any Wake_Lock but figured one of the 3rd party libraries did.

After some googling, I found that I can find the merged Manifest file in the build/outputs/logs. I found the file and found a Wake_lock but wasn't sure who it was attributed to.

Is it the lines above or below it that say who is requesting the Wake_Lock? Or better put is it being caused by Butterknife or Google Play Services?

Here is the excerpt that I found the Wake_Lock in:

```
MERGED from [com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0] /Users/SamMyxer/jackrabbit/sl_saplingandroidbase/SaplingLearning/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/23.3.0/AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-43
MERGED from [com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1] /Users/SamMyxer/jackrabbit/sl_saplingandroidbase/SaplingLearning/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.jakewharton/butterknife/8.0.1/AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-43
    android:targetSdkVersion
        INJECTED from /Users/SamMyxer/jackrabbit/sl_saplingandroidbase/SaplingLearning/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
        INJECTED from /Users/SamMyxer/jackrabbit/sl_saplingandroidbase/SaplingLearning/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
    android:minSdkVersion
        INJECTED from /Users/SamMyxer/jackrabbit/sl_saplingandroidbase/SaplingLearning/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
        INJECTED from /Users/SamMyxer/jackrabbit/sl_saplingandroidbase/SaplingLearning/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
uses-permission#android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
ADDED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0] /Users/SamMyxer/jackrabbit/sl_saplingandroidbase/SaplingLearning/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-measurement/8.3.0/AndroidManifest.xml:24:5-67
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0] /Users/SamMyxer/jackrabbit/sl_saplingandroidbase/SaplingLearning/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-measurement/8.3.0/AndroidManifest.xml:24:5-67
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0] /Users/SamMyxer/jackrabbit/sl_saplingandroidbase/SaplingLearning/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-measurement/8.3.0/AndroidManifest.xml:24:5-67
    android:name
        ADDED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0] /Users/SamMyxer/jackrabbit/sl_saplingandroidbase/SaplingLearning/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-measurement/8.3.0/AndroidManifest.xml:24:22-65
provider#com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
uses-permission#android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
ADDED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0] /Users/SamMyxer/jackrabbit/sl_saplingandroidbase/SaplingLearning/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-measurement/8.3.0/AndroidManifest.xml:24:5-67
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0] /Users/SamMyxer/jackrabbit/sl_saplingandroidbase/SaplingLearning/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-measurement/8.3.0/AndroidManifest.xml:24:5-67
MERGED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0] /Users/SamMyxer/jackrabbit/sl_saplingandroidbase/SaplingLearning/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-measurement/8.3.0/AndroidManifest.xml:24:5-67
```

`WAKE_LOCK` is being added by your `com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0` dependency.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CommonsWare. That file is a bit tricky to read.

Comment: @user3520299: Yes, it is not the most user-friendly report. :-(