# Android App: "play-services-gcm" requires "play-services-measurement"?

Tags: android, optimization, google-cloud-messaging

I just changed my Android project - which uses push notifications - to the latest gcm service (9.0.2) in my gradle settings and got the message to download the play-services-measurement to the same version.

Now I'm asking myself why this is necessary. I explicitly don't want any app measurements in my app nor do I want Google to do any on my behalf. I also don't have this in my dependencies so it surely comes from gcm.

Is this unavoidable? Does the *com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm* always require these measurements? After all, I only want "notifications".
Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any resource about this, only the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#september_2015_-_v81) from the Google APIs for Android, it's stated here that Application Measurement
adds the measurement package, which contains features for collecting anonymous statistics on application events such as when a user first opens your application and on in-app purchase. While this data is not collected unless correctly configured.

If you want to opt-out of reporting to these statistics, you can add the following resource to your application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<integer name="google_app_measurement_enable">0</integer>
</resources>
```

Also from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713031/reading-build-outputs-logs-file-from-gradle-android-studio), the `WAKE_LOCK` is being added by play-services-measurement dependency.